# Modeling an abstract base class in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, inheritance, protocols

I have a Cocoa Touch class `BaseViewController`:

```
class BaseViewController: Named, UIViewController {
    open var name = "Emma"

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        self.doSomethingImportant(self.name)
    }
}

protocol Named {
    var name: String
}
```

The intent behind `BaseViewController` is that all view controllers in my app will be derived from it, because it does something important in `viewDidAppear()` with `name`.

However, I'm trying to model this in a way where it'll be a compile-time error to subclass from `BaseViewController` without specifying `name`, and *not* have to supply a default `name` value in the base class. In other words:

- Can I have BaseViewController *require* that its subclasses implement Named without it implementing Named itself?
- If not, how else can I achieve this within the paradigm of Cocoa Touch plus Protocol-Oriented Programming?